# Icon font - icon height bigger than expected

Tags: fonts, css, glyph

I'm using an icon font generated by `fontastic.me` in my project. However, all icons are a little bit higher as expected.

Snippet here:

```css
.icon-camera {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <span class="icon-camera"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

What can cause this effect, and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 20):

Font Awesome has developed a solution to deal with this issue. I mirrored their solution by creating a new class called ".icon" in my font.css file. It seems to work well with Fontastic too.(Make sure you add your font where I have "your-icon-font-here").

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 "your-icon-font-here";
    font-size: inherit;
 }

<i class="icon icon-tag"></i>
```

Comment: OP please accept this answer! This is the only thing on the internet that solves this mind boggling issue!

Comment: @Andrew Dotson ... You are a hero of the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a line height issue. Unclear about other glyphs in the character set, but using your example this CSS—which uses `line-height: 50%;`, `display: inline-block;` and `position: relative;` seems to work. My only concern is the `line-height: 50%;` is truly only for the example you are showing. So glyphs of different heights might just need other values. But experiment to see if this works for you or if the concept reveals a more flexible solution.

```css
.icon-camera {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #ff0000;
  line-height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <span class="icon-camera"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do what im going to tell you, then you should make `icons.css` file offline. I mean not referencing in `<link rel= ...` and using it between `<style></style>` in the `head` part.
In the file:

```
https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/icons.css
```

You can see this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "app-icons";
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.eot");
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.svg#1411745016") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

You should add this `font-size:small` That should look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "app-icons";
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.eot");
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/fonts/1411745016.svg#1411745016") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: small;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.icon-camera {
  display: inline-block; /* add line */
  line-height: 1; /* add line */
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.icon-camera:before {
  display: inline-block; /* add line */
  vertical-align: top; /* add line. maybe it's not necessary */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/FsVBbT8KX9p5tE8xXk4xmE/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <span class="icon-camera"></span>
</body>
</html>
```